# Port Forwarding between two CentOS servers

Tags: centos, iptables, remote-access, port-forwarding

I have two servers (Both running CentOS 5.5 64-Bit)

One server is connected to a public network and has a public IP address which I can use to SSH into it remotely. The other server is connected to Server 1 through a private network.

I would like to know how I can forward a port (say 20222) on server 1 to port 22 on server 2 so that I can connect to server 2 using any SSH client by using the public IP of server 1 and port 20222.

The public network of server 1 is connected through interface eth0 and private network is connected through eth1

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Kalpesh

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this creating a ssh tunnel :

```
ssh -L 20222:server_2_private_IP_address:22 server_1_public_IP_address
```

You could also add this to your ~/.ssh/config if you have one as:

```
Host foo
  Hostname server_1_public_IP_address
  User ...
  ...
  LocalForward 20222 server_2_private_IP_address:22
```

After starting a ssh to server_1_public_IP_address, you should be able to start a new ssh session to server_2 using

```
ssh -p 20222 localhost
```

Never tried it, but should work with any ssh client, point it to localhost and por 20222.

And read

```
man ssh
```

All this is explained in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install stone (tcp/udp open source tunneling software)  by running and then run the following command as root

```
wget http://www.gcd.org/sengoku/stone/stone-2.3e.tar.gz
tar xzf ./stone-2.3e.tar.gz
cd ./stone-2.3d-2.3.2.7
make linux
cp ./stone /usr/bin/
cd ../
rm -Rf ./stone-2.3d-2.3.2.7
```

then as user run the following command

```
stone -D server1:20222/tcp server2:22/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming server 1 has external address 1.2.3.4 and internal address 10.0.0.1, and server 2 has internal address 10.0.0.2 and no existing default route:

on server 1:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20222 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:22
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

on server 2:

```
route add default gw 10.0.0.1
```

None of these settings is persistent, that is, they won't survive a reboot.  If they work, we can discuss how to make them permanent.

Answer (score 0):

MadHatter has the iptables answer for you if you want to go that route.

For quick and dirty redirects during migrations and stuff, I have used redir

Something like this on Server 1:

```
  redir --lport=20222 --caddr=$IP_OF_SERVER_2 --cport=22
```

Again, that just runs in the foreground and won't survive a reboot, but it's such a handy command that I thought it belonged in this discussion.